# how to do a 301 permanent redirect in angular

Tags: angular, iis

I am using angular(version 10) Universal to serve my web application also my web server is IIS.
how can I do a 301 permanent redirect from this url : https://myapp.com/a to this url : https://myapp.com/b .
I have tried [this solution](https://gist.github.com/KostyaEsmukov/ce8a6486b2ea596c138770ae393b196f) but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a web.config file like this :

```
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url=".*NEWPDS.*" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
                    </rule>    

           <rule name="URL1" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url="^onetoberedirected.html" ignoreCase="true" />
               <action type="Redirect" url="desiredPage" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rules>
                <outboundRules>    
                </outboundRules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    
</configuration>
```